# SignalR client side not always called depending on the browser and / or webpage

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, signalr, client-side

I am having some inconsistent behavior with SignalR on my web application. It works most of the time except a few pages of the web app, it does not show up in IE 11 and Chrome. Interestingly, it does not work on pages where I have some Telerik components (UI for ASP.NET AJAX 2015.3.1104) but I don't know if this is related.

Here is my hub js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.logging = true;
connection.start();

$.connection.eCDHub.logging = true;

//get  hub
var ecdHub = $.connection.eCDHub;

//on starting page => join the ecd hub to receive notifications
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    ecdHub.server.joinECDHub(instId);
    try{
        ecdHub.server.showRequestToAll(null, 0).done(console.log("showRequestToAll"));
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("error (" + err+ ")");
    }
    console.log("Connected to notifications (" + instId + ")");
}).fail(function (reason) {
    console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
});

//on receiving ecd notification
ecdHub.client.showRequest = function (ecd) {
    console.log("eCd notification received");
    if (typeof displayComingRequest == 'function') {
        displayComingRequest(ecd);
    }
    //$("#ecdAlertModel").show();
}

ecdHub.client.showRequestToAll = function (ecd) {
    console.log("notification received for all");
    //displayComingRequest(ecd);
    //$("#ecdAlertModel").show();
}

ecdHub.client.showMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log("Message received: " + msg);
}
});
```

Now in Firefox I see the following happening:

```
[12:24:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource calling close().  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = false.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:31 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Window unloading, stopping the connection.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5'.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://192.168.1.251/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=XloZHlV2pNdtdLr%2BeR%2FTDSOKICodsv7MI%2Bj1Zt7rp%2FWs8kOasiDMst9jTYB4scMJsVMEHLxX%2BH0ccG%2BAT9Iunmq2BfT5jzSGCLQALNVw%2FxMW5iPcLFQer2zCWJub5FK8NYzw3Q%3D%3D&tid=10'.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
[12:24:37 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000  jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9:3362
showRequestToAll  hubs.js:25:58
Connected to notifications (101)  hubs.js:30:9
notification received for all
```

So clearly my client side method showRequestToAll() is called. However, Chrome for example, I see this:

```
[12:24:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9 
[12:24:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9 
[12:24:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://192.168.1.251/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProto…nZfR%2F6CVhvHqokc6b6DmNjsrPshxkAfZgCZr1Bcn0P%2FQGz5oe7SRc63F3w%3D%3D&tid=6'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9
[12:24:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: EventSourceconnected.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9 
[12:24:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9 
[12:24:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js:9 
[12:24:30 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000 hubs.js:25 
showRequestToAll hubs.js:30 
Connected to notifications (101)
```

And in IE11:

```
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5'.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport starting.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: This browser doesn't support SSE.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to fall back.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport starting.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Binding to iframe's load event.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport connected. Initiating start request.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
[12:24:40 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 30000
showRequestToAll
Connected to notifications (101)
[12:24:45 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)] SignalR: foreverFrame transport timed out when trying to connect.
```

Any idea of what is going on between browsers? On other pages, it will work just fine in IE and Chrome. It seems to work every where with FF.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue without totally understanding how it fixed it.

I was using Jquery 3.0.0 and SignalR 2.2.1. I **downgraded to JQuery 2.2.4 and SignalR 2.0.1** and it works fine... If anybody has an explanation I would be glad to know it.